# Refresh page after delete photo

Tags: javascript, ajax, refresh, reload

Hi I have function in javascript where I delete photos from database and from server. It work fine, I delete photo but this photo is still in my browser. I have question. How can I refresh only on javascript side?

```
 container.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                if(e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON'){
                     var id = e.target.dataset.type;
                   var r = confirm("Are You sure to delete?");
if (r == true) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?r=gallery/deletep&name='+id,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
} 
                }
    });
```

Now I treid to add

> location.reload();

after ajax but I don't want to refresh all page. How Can i delete dynamically from browser?

Comment: In the callback of the AJAX.

Comment: but there I still must to used location.reload()? This function reload me all page I want to do like refresh only by browse side

Comment: No, when the AJAX finishes and executes its success callback, you can remove any elements attached to the DOM from within the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to reload the whole page to remove the image. Use [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) API from jQuery in the success callback in AJAX call.

```
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?r=gallery/deletep&name='+id,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response){
       $('img#id').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

OK in this type of situation you have two options. Either you load contents using AJAX request or remove the element from `DOM` either using class or id of that element.
So what happens is if you have loaded content using AJAX you can load all those contents again after successful deletion of image.

`$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?r=gallery/deletep&name='+id,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response) {
               $(e.target).remove();
        }
});`

OR,

`$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?r=gallery/deletep&name='+id,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response) {
               // use next ajax query to load content on DOM
        }
});`